# jqgrid row height expanding when adding both icon and text

Tags: javascript, html, css, jqgrid

[image: jqgrid now]

Im Using jqgrid and I want an anchor tag which links to a page with current row id.

The icon and text appear in seperate line how do I get them into the same line

[image: jqgrid expected]

Code:

```js
function addLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject){

     return "<a href=detail_view.html?id="+ options.rowId +"><div class='ui-icon ui-icon-search'></div>asdas</a>";
    };
```

Comment: function addLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
     return "<a href=detail_view.html?id="+ options.rowId +"><div class='ui-icon ui-icon-search'></div></a>";
    };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you need just use `style='display:inline-block'` instead of `<div>` for the icon element.

Comment: @ron404: I tried this and can see that jQuery UI CSS set `display:block`. So you can set `style='display:inline-block'` to fix the problem.